# When I have created new empty activity android studio project this error is shown

Tags: android, android-studio

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6qv5y.png)

```
Could not load wrapper properties from 'E:\demo3\gradle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.properties'.
```

I have install android studio two times but same problem

Comment: clean, rebuild your project

Comment: Has rebuilding and cleaning solved your problem? as suggested by @chandmohd

Comment: yes solved issue